# Getting Configuration error for Adyen react-native for android

Tags: android, react-native, adyen

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Cannot get property 'adyenReactNativeRedirectScheme' on extra properties extension as it does not exist.

Below are the steps I did to configure for android

**app/build.gradle :**

`manifestPlaceholders = [redirectScheme: rootProject.ext.adyenReactNativeRedirectScheme]`

**MainActivity.kt:**

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import com.adyenreactnativesdk.AdyenCheckout.handleIntent
import com.adyenreactnativesdk.AdyenCheckout.setLauncherActivity

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(null)
    setLauncherActivity(this)
  }

  override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    handleIntent(intent!!)
  }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml :**

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:host="${applicationId}" android:scheme="${redirectScheme}" />
</intent-filter>
```